# Multiple Line String to separated new strings for every line

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing, jsoup

I have the following code. I am using the jsoup library to retrieve the URLs from a website; after that, I am checking if the URLs contain the keyword I want, and list them in another string. My problem is that I am not able to retrieve only one URL.
Have a look at my code:

```
// Get the webpage and parse it.
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.examplepage").get();

// Get the anchors with href attribute.
// Or, you can use doc.select("a") to get all the anchors.
org.jsoup.select.Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

// Iterate over all the links and process them.
for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element link : links) {
     String scrapedlinks += link.attr("abs:href")+"\n" ;
     String scrapedlinks3 ="";                  
}

 String[] links2 = links.split("\n");
 for (String newlink  : hulklinks  ) {
        if (newlink("mysearchterm")) {
            scrapedlinks3 +=newlink ;
            String[] scrapedlines = scrapedlinks3.split("\n" );
        }
 }
```

Comment: Could you be more specific in what you are trying to accomplish?  Could you post the URL you are parsing or some sample HTML?  Could you format your code to look a little cleaner?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier if you directly store your urls in an Arraylist:

```
Arraylist<String> urls = new Arraylist<String>();
for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element link : links)
    urls.add(link.attr("abs:href"));
```

After this you can easy access them with

```
urls.get(i);
```